# Firebase Authentication with Angular

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, angular5

### What I'm Using

- Angular 5
- AngularFire5
- Firebase & Firestore

### What I'm Trying to Achieve

I am trying to make a simple authentication/login & registration system. I actually have one already made, though I am running into some issues, and I want to make sure I am going about the best way to setup authentication.

### What I have So Far

#### auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  authState: any = null;
  email = '';
  username = '';
  password = '';
  errorMessage = '';
  error: {name: string, message: string} = {name: '', message: ''};

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
      this.authState = auth
    });
  }
  get isUserEmailLoggedIn(): boolean {
    if (this.authState !== null) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  get currentUser(): any {
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState : null;
  }
  get currentUserId(): string {
    return (this.authState !== null) ? this.authState.uid : ''
  }
  get currentUserName(): string {
    return this.authState['email']
  }
  signUpWithEmail(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        this.authState = user
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      });
  }
  loginWithEmail(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        this.authState = user
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        throw error
      });
  }
  signOut(): void {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }
  onSignUp(): void {
    this.clearErrorMessage()
    if (this.validateForm(this.email, this.password)) {
      this.signUpWithEmail(this.email, this.password)
        .then(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home'])
        }).catch(_error => {
          this.error = _error
          this.router.navigate(['/register'])
        })
    }
  }
  onLoginEmail(): void {
    this.clearErrorMessage()
    if (this.validateForm(this.email, this.password)) {
      this.loginWithEmail(this.email, this.password)
        .then(() => this.router.navigate(['/home']))
        .catch(_error => {
          this.error = _error
          this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        })
    }
  }
  validateForm(email: string, password: string): boolean {
    if (email.length === 0) {
      this.errorMessage = 'Please enter Email!'
      return false
    }
    if (password.length === 0) {
      this.errorMessage = 'Please enter Password!'
      return false
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      this.errorMessage = 'Password should be at least 6 characters!'
      return false
    }
    this.errorMessage = ''
    return true

  }
  clearErrorMessage() {
    this.errorMessage = '';
    this.error = {name: '', message: ''};
  }
}
```

#### link.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface Link { uid: string; url: string; shortURL: string; clicks: number }

@Injectable()
export class LinkService implements OnInit {
  url: string;
  shortURL: string;
  showAlert: boolean;
  links: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private afs: AngularFirestore) {
        this.links = afs.collection('Links').valueChanges();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  createShortURL() {
    var text = '';
    var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var length = 6;

    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return this.shortURL = text;
  }
  addLink() {
    if (this.authService.isUserEmailLoggedIn) {
      this.createShortURL();
      this.afs.collection('Links').doc(this.shortURL).set({
        'uid': this.authService.currentUserId,
        'url': this.url,
        'shortURL': this.shortURL,
        'clicks': 0
      });
      this.clearFields();
      this.showAlert = false;
    } else {
      this.showAlert = true;
    }
  }
  clearFields() {
    return this.url = '';
  }
}
```

### Where I'm Stuck

With the information provided. I am trying to get the currentUserID in the link.service.ts though it is coming back as undefined. However with the addLink() function, `this.authService.isUserEmailLoggedIn` works perfectly fine, and Im not sure why it is not returning the correct value otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get id like this.

```
 this.items = this.itemCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
          return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data();
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
          });
        });
```

Comment: Could you explain what this is exactly doing, I’m not sure I understand 100% so I would love some further explination if you are able to provide it.

Comment: In short if you need to access id you must use `snapshotChanges()` here is what docs said : `snapshotChanges()` When you need the document data but also want to keep around metadata. This metadata provides you the underyling DocumentReference and document id. Having the document's id around makes it easier to use data manipulation method.
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#streaming-document-data

Comment: I’m trying to retrieve the Current User ID which is part of Auth. I know how to grab data from a document, but what I’m trying to figure out is when I run for instance, ‘this.authService.currentUserId();’ it’s logging as undefined. I’m not sure why ‘if (this.authService.isUserEmailLoggedIn)’ works but ‘this.authService.currentUserId();’ does not!

Answer (score 0):

`currentUserId()` is a function you should use `'uid': this.authService.currentUserId(),`